# TCP and UDP combined

Tags: sockets, networking, tcp, udp

I am planning on using TCP/IP and UDP protocols *together* for my game server. I have alread setup the server, in java, and the client, in c++, and had them both connected with a nice gui using the TCP/IP protocol. I need their to be UDP interactions since the UDP protocol allows the loss of packets which is essential for an online game that has position and other updates being transferred that wouldn't be beneficial to resend if an error occurs. My problem occurred when I tried converting my client and server to the UDP protocol. In java I have noticed that it will be harder to create a UDP connection because it isn't as easy as binding to a port and awaiting connections IMHO so:

- Is it possible via the UDP protocol, or any other protocol, to have my server "*broadcast*" data, such as entity location, and allow the client to receive the data without having to pragmatically establish a permanent connection to that server.
- If the above is a no, is it possible to use the UDP and TCP/IP protocols together without having to establish two separate connection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible via the UDP protocol, or any other protocol, to have my server "broadcast" data, such as entity location, and allow the client to receive the data without having to pragmatically establish a permanent connection to that server.

That's all you can do, because UDP has no notion of a permanent connection. All it supports is datagrams.

> If the above is a no, is it possible to use the UDP and TCP/IP protocols together without having to establish two separate connection.

UDP is connectionless, there wouldn't be a "separate connection". Probably the best way to think about is that the connection is the TCP thing, but data can also be sent using UDP while the connection exists.

Since UDP doesn't always work over the Internet, I would strongly suggest separating the transport layer from other program logic. Your transport layer can make the TCP connection and, using the TCP connection, agree to try UDP. If UDP works, your layer can route data that's best sent over UDP over the UDP connection. If UDP fails, you can include that data in the TCP connection. You'll need to design your own encapsulation/messaging protocol to be used over the TCP connection, including the ability to negotiate and test a "side" UDP connection.

You should keep in mind that TCP does a lot more than just retransmissions, and if you need many of the other things, you're probably better off using TCP than UDP. This is especially true because the TCP layer is developed by network experts and built into the operating system and it's unlikely you can do a better job, even if you don't have to worry about retransmissions. Some of those things are:

Session setup, tear-down, and tracking
Last ACK handling and Byzantine failure
Slow start
Checksumming and verification
Exponential backoff
Reordering
Duplicate detection
Path MTU detection
Path bandwidth detection
Acknowledgements with piggybacking
Dead connection detection
"Short" packet avoidance
And more.

Comment: Ok so in essence i can create a connection between the client and server so that the server can obtain the data from the client, but the client obtains the data through the server via UDP. Thanks that's all that i needed.

Comment: You may find that the client and server need to exchange a few packets with each other to get the connection working. And you may find that if the client doesn't send a datagram to the server every so often, the ability to exchange UDP datagrams times out at the NAT device. Punch "NAT penetration" or "NAT traversal" to learn more.

Comment: But in a game such as Call of duty it wouldn't be efficient to retransmit entity location if it fails at first, this would cause unnecessary lag. So for that sole purpose i need an alternative.

Comment: The thing is, it's a package deal. You get that one small minus, but you get a ton of huge pluses. (See the list at the end of my answer.) And all this is implemented in (or at least with) the operating system by experts tuned for the CPU, network hardware, and so on.

Comment: Yea I understand, I never planned on completly cutting out TCP/IP

Comment: Also, though, what I have seen so far is that in order to transmit data efficiently with TCP to all clients connected, lets say 50, threads are needed. And even with thread pools there are a limit...

Comment: On the send side, it makes no difference. You could use 50 threads to send UDP datagrams to 50 clients if you wanted to. It's true that it's a bit easier to use fewer threads on the receive side with UDP.

Comment: I mean that using threads for TCP would be expensive as UDP broadcasts the data threads aren't necessary.

Comment: Broadcasting won't help you, you can't broadcast over the Internet. The reason you might need fewer threads with UDP and a naive design is that you only have to receive on one socket. For sending, it's identical.

Comment: I always thought that it were the other way around and that the UDP server would broadcast on a single thread, that is what the question is asking anyways.

Comment: You can send to any number of places from a single thread with both TCP and UDP, so long as you have a non-blocking send function and some way to manage buffering, handle partial sends, and so on. (It sounds like you're getting way, way ahead of yourself and should learn TCP inside out before you even think of trying to handle two things at once. Consider Boost ASIO for the C++ side.)

Comment: I am using the qt networking library that comes built in with the qt gui library

Answer (score 0):

UDP is connectionless, it works by just sending datagrams to the receiver and hope that it will reach the destination (no confirmation or anything like TCP)

Take a look at this example:

[Java UDP server and client](https://systembash.com/a-simple-java-udp-server-and-udp-client/)

And maybe read up on the documentation:

[Writing a datagram client and server](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/datagrams/clientServer.html)